# .NET Core 3 API Model Binding Complex Type with Angular 10

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an Angular 10 application that calls a .NET Core 3 API. I have a complex type that I am trying to model bind on a POST but running into an issue.  On the Angular side, I have a type with an array and on the .NET side, the type I'm trying to bind to includes a List<>. I'm trying to get the array to model bind with the List<>. The array values are correct on the POST but I hit the error in the controller on the .NET side, specifically with the parameter when trying to bind. Below is the error I'm receiving along with my code.

Error....

> " Bad Request status: 400"
>
> "The JSON value could not be converted to
> App.Models.VideoCategoryModel[ ]"

Angular Types...

```
export class Video {
    constructor(public id?: number,
        public title?: string,
        public date?: string,
        public description?: string,
        public url?: string,
        public enabled?: boolean,
        public categories?: VideoCategory[]){ }
}

export class VideoCategory {
    constructor(public id?: number,
        public name?: string){ }
}
```

Here is the JSON being sent to the API

```
{
    "title":"Test Title",
    "date":"2020-12-09",
    "description":"Test Description",
    "url":"C:\\fakepath\\Capture2.JPG",
    "categories":{
        "id":101,
        "name":"Platform Tutorials"
    }
}
```

.NET Core Controller Code....

Models...

```
public class VideoModel
{
    public VideoModel()
    {
        Categories = new List<VideoCategoryModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public List<VideoCategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class VideoCategoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller...

```
    [HttpPost("addvideo")]
    public IActionResult AddVideo([FromBody] VideoModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            //var id = _service.AddVideo(_mapper.Map<VideoModel, TaVideo>(model));
            //return Ok(id);

            return Ok();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Failed to add the new video: {ex}");
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm obviously missing something or need to refactor the way I'm binding but I don't know the best way to do it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the complete json that is posted to .net core API? Looks like json is invalid. It should be like this  `categories:[{"id": 101, "name": "Platform Tutorials" }, {"id": 102, "name": "Platform Tutorials 2"}] `

Comment: @MohsinMehmood - I have updated the question to include the JSON being sent to the API.  Looks like I may be missing the brackets? [ ].

Comment: Hi @jayh, any updates about this case? If the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

> "The JSON value could not be converted to App.Models.VideoCategoryModel[ ]"

Based on your `VideoModel` class, we can find that `Categories` property should be a collection of `VideoCategoryModel` object. As @MohsinMehmood mentioned in comment, you should provide an array for categories field on your Angular frontend code.

```
"categories":[{
    "id":101,
    "name":"Platform Tutorials"
}]
```

Besides, please note that you are passing file path in `url` field, but the property is named as `VideoUrl` in model class, to make model binding work well, you can try to specify the property name that is present in the JSON when serializing and deserializing with following code snippet.

```
[JsonPropertyName("Url")]
public string VideoUrl { get; set; }
```